# How can I save parts of the URL to the database when a certain page is viewed?

Tags: 7

Can a page be created the normal way (not by module) in Drupal 7, using Content Type an so forth, yet still trigger a module and pass a variable from the URL.

The idea is to let the web team create their page as normal, but require the last part of the path to be a variable. Then a module is called to take that variable and do magic with it.

We want the module to work with the variable in the background, NOT render a page.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to give more specifics as to what the code will accomplish with that variable is in order to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: Marketing creates the page with a URL that contains a variable representing the user. User gets an email and clicks on button that goes to page. When they get to the page the module is triggered to collect the variable data from the URL. The module will then save that value to a DB. That's all.

Comment: You can take a look at the statistics module, perhaps it already does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> Marketing creates the page with a URL that contains a variable
> representing the user. User gets an email and clicks on button that
> goes to page. When they get to the page the module is triggered to
> collect the variable data from the URL. The module will then save that
> value to a DB.

Use [template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.7.x)

Have the URL in the e-mail formatted like this:

```
example.com/node/1?param1=value1?param2=value2
```

If it's required that the user must be logged in

```
example.com/user/login?destination=node/1?param1=value1?param2=value2
```

I used /node/1 as an example, but you can use its url alias instead if it has one.

Then in your mymodule.module file

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
   if ($node->type == 'article') { // checks its Article Content Type
     $params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
     if (!empty($params)) {
       // do more magic to get each param value on its own
       // save to the DB
     }
   }
}
```